# Setting the directory to include subdirectories using html2text

Tags: php, html, mysql, subdirectory

Long time reader, first time poster. I know just enough about php to be dangerous and this is my first BIG project using it.

Some background:

I have over 1 million (yes, million) .html files that were generated from an old news gathering program. These .html files contain important archive information that needs to be searched on daily basis. I have yet to get to other servers which might very well have more so 2-3 million+ is not out of the question.

I am taking these .html files and transferring them into a mysql database. At least, so far, the code has worked wonderfully with several hundred test files. I'll attach the code at the end.

The problem starts when the .html files are archived, and it's a function of the box generating the archive which cannot be changed, is the files go into folders. They are broken down like this

> archives>year>month>file.html

so an example is

> ```
> archives>2002>05may>lots and lots of files.html
> archives>2002>06june>lots and lots of files.html
> archives>2002>07july>lots and lots of files.html
> ```

With help and research, I wrote code to strip the files of markup that includes html2text and simple_html_dom and put the information from each tag in the proper fields in my database, which works great. But ALL of the files need to be moved to the same directory for it to work. Again, over a million and possibly more for other severs takes a REALLY long time to move. I am using a batch file to robocopy the files now.

My question is this:

Can I use some sort of wildcard to define all of the subdirectories so I don't have to move all of the files and they can stat in their respective directories?

Top of my code:

```
// Enter absolute path of folder with HTML files in it here (include trailing slash):
$directory = "C:\\wamp1\\www\\name\\search\\files\\";
```

The subdirectories are under the `files` directory.

In my searches for an answer, I have seen "why would you want to do that?" or other questions asking about .exe files or .bat files in the directories and how it could be dangerous so don't do it. My question is just for these html files so there is nothing being called or running and no danger.

Here is my code for stripping the html into the database. Again, works great, but I would like to skip the step of having to move all of the files into one directory.

```
<?php

// Enter absolute path of folder with HTML files in it here (include trailing slash):
$directory = "C:\\wamp1\\www\\wdaf\\search\\files\\";

// Enter MySQL database variables here:
$db_hostname = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "password";
$db_name = "dbname";
$db_tablename = "dbtablename";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Include these files to strip all characters that we don't want
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
include_once("html2text.php");

//Connect to the database
mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password) or trigger_error("Unable to connect to the database host: " . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or trigger_error("Unable to switch to the database: " . mysql_error()); 

//scan the directory and look for all the htmls files
$files = scandir($directory);
for ($filen = 0; $filen < count($files); $filen++)  {
    $html = file_get_html($directory . $files[$filen]);

    // first check if $html->find exists
    if (method_exists($html,"find")) {

        // then check if the html element exists to avoid trying to parse non-html
        if ($html->find('html')) {

                    //Get the filename of the file from which it will extract   
            $filename = $files[$filen];

            //define the path of the files
            $path = "./files/";

            //Combine the patha and filename
            $fullpath = $path . $filename;


            // Get our variables from the HTML: Starts with 0 as the title field so use alternate ids starting with 1 for the information
            $slug = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 8)));
            $tape = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 9)));
            $format0 = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 10)));
            $time0 = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 11)));
            $writer = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 12)));
            $newscast = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 13)));
            $modified = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 14)));
            $by0 = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 15)));
            $productionCues = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 16)));
            $script = mysql_real_escape_string(convert_html_to_text($html->find('td', 18)));

            // Insert variables into a row in the MySQL table:
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $db_tablename . " (`path`, `fullpath`, `filename`, `slug`, `tape`, `format0`, `time0`, `writer`, `newscast`, `modified`, `by0`, `productionCues`, `script`) VALUES ('" . $path . "', '" . $fullpath . "', '" . $filename . "', '" . $slug . "', '" . $tape . "', '" . $format0 . "', '" . $time0 . "', '" . $writer . "', '" . $newscast . "', '" . $modified . "', '" . $by0 . "', '" . $productionCues . "', '" . $script . "');"; 
            $sql_return = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed: " . mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update this post with a answer to my question that works quite well. With some help, we found that scandir used recursively to create an array would work. 
I thought I'd post this so if anyone else was looking to do something similar, they would be able wouldn't have to look far! I know I like to see answers!

The code is from the second user-contributed note here with a few modifications: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

so in my code above, I replaced

```
//scan the directory and look for all the htmls files
$files = scandir($directory);
for ($filen = 0; $filen < count($files); $filen++)  {
    $html = file_get_html($directory . $files[$filen]);
```

with

```
function import_dir($directory, $db_tablename) { 

   $cdir = scandir($directory); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            // Item in this directory is sub-directory...
            import_dir($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value,$db_tablename); 
         } 
         else 
            // Item in this directory is a file...
         { 
            $html = file_get_html($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
```

and then for the filenames, replaced

```
//Get the filename of the file from which it will extract   
            $filename = $files[$filen];

            //define the path of the files
            $path = "./files/";

            //Combine the patha and filename
            $fullpath = $path . $filename;
```

with

```
//Get the filename of the file from which it will extract   
                    $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

                    //define the path of the files
                    $path = mysql_real_escape_string($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

                    //Combine the patha and filename
                    $fullpath = $path . $value;
```

Thanks to those who answered!

Mike

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how long it would take before your PHP query times out, but there is an inbuilt function [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) which sounds like it might do the trick for you.

Comment: thany you Pete, 
I have tried a few things, but keep getting the error

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RecursiveIteratorIterator::__construct() must implement interface Traversable

And can't get passed it